# Angular.js ng-class visible if true from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have Cordova app based on angular.js and these 2 documents:

**app.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl as myApp" ng-class="myApp.isWindows() ? 'windows' : ''">
```

and **app.controller**

```
MyAppCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function MyAppCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isWindows = isWindows;    
}

function isWindows() {
    return true;
}
```

I have to check something in `isWindows` function and if condition be `true` then return `true` - show class `windows` in html. But this is not working right now. I found a tutorial where was sample like this, but this is not working for me. Can you help me?

Comment: It was just copy - paste mistake, no I dont have any console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the wrong [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) syntax, use this instead:

```
<div ng-controller="MyAppCtrl as myApp" ng-class="{windows: myApp.isWindows()}">...</div>
```